# How to add a number to a time before ordering (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Running a very basic database including details on customers, car parks and parking sessions, I would like to return all parking sessions ordered by the end time in ascending order for a particular car.

However i only have the beginning time and length(in hours, stored as an int) of each session.
Below is my best attempt however this only orders by the start time.
(TimeDateStart in this case is the start time and date of the parking session stored as datetime datatype)

It is the order by part I cannot figure out, the rest works as desired and returns the parking sessions for this car.

```
SELECT *

FROM ParkingSession

JOIN Customer ON ParkingSession.CustID = Customer.CustID

WHERE Customer.Registration = "BH34 JHN"

ORDER BY (TIME(DateTimeStart) + Hours) ASC;
```

The Tables this is being run on is as follows (I dont think the customer table is needed but i thought i would include it anyway):

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Registration CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    CreditCard BLOB NOT NULL,
    CVC BLOB NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL);

    CREATE TABLE ParkingSession (
    CarParkID INT,
    CustID INT,
    DateTimeStart DATETIME,
    Hours TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY(CarParkID,CustID,DateTimeStart),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Carpark FOREIGN KEY (CarParkID) REFERENCES CarPark(CarParkID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Customer FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer(CustID));
```

Comment: Add you table description (columns names and data types) so it's easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an interval of some hours to a datetime. That's

```
ORDER BY DateTimeStart + INTERVAL Hours HOUR
```